# JavaFX Text in/on Polygon

Tags: java, text, javafx, polygon

I wanted to take a text (javafx.scene.text) and put it on a polygon.

I tried it with a Group (javafx.scene.group) by trying this tutorial: [tutorial on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628410/how-to-center-wrap-truncate-text-to-fit-within-rectangle-in-javafx-2-1)

This doesn't work with the text.setClip(Polygon).

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ch.berufsbildungscenter.notiztool.gui.control.BbcPolygon$1.run(BbcPolygon.java:33)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there another way to get a Text onto a polygon?

Thanks
Peace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setClip() has different purpose. You can check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setClip(javafx.scene.Node)) 
 To easily put Text on a Polygon or any other node, you can use [javafx.scene.layout.StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) like this:
         `StackPane stack=new StackPane();
 stack.getChildren().add(polygonInstance);
 stack.getChildren().add(textInstance);`
 The node last added will be on top.